# Applying second discount in Woocommerce - after bulk discount

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, cart, discount

in my online store I have applied a bulk discount (i.e. a percentage reduction based on the quantity purchased). This works great. I also want to apply a second discount mechanism where the customer can select a criteria from a dropdown box and a discount will be applied again. This second category is schedule i.e. daily, weekly, monthly for a service - ie how often the service purchased will be delivered. This will reduce the unit price i.e. for one product.

I am not using a subscription method for this as the customer will be invoiced once a month - i.e. not based on which drop down (daily, weekly) the select.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: wrong site for this kind of question